# There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path on iOS 10

Tags: xcode, swift3, uistoryboard, ios10, uistoryboardsegue

I keep getting this error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'There doesn't seem to be a
>   valid compiled storyboard at path
>   '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/43F5F727-9B69-404E-A320-22AE93547B73/vContacts.app/Base.lproj/Main.storyboardc'

when I use this below line in iOS 10's devices. It works fine in iOS 9

```
let mainST = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

I already set targeted family device to 1/2 (iPhone & iPad) and clean the project but still got this error. How to fix it?

Comment: I'm getting this too. There's some major breakage happening with production apps in iOS 10. Something is wrong in how Apple have configured the bundle.

Comment: Anybody has an update for this? I'm having similar in macOS